# Algorithm to find out the identity element of a group?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I did something like this (in pseudocode):

```
 for x = 0 to 3
  for y = 0 to 3
    id1 = m[x][y] * m[y][x];
    id2 = m[y][x] * m[x][y];
    if id1 != m[x][y] or id1 != id2 then
      nn = nn + 1;
    else
      en = id1;
    endif
  endfor
 endfor
 if nn = 0 then
      print("There is an identity element: ", en);
      a := a + 1;
 else
      print("There isn't an identity element.");
 endif
```

When I run it, with 1,2,3,4 as my set and multiplication as the operation, it returns "There isn't an identity element.", so I guess there is something wrong with my logic here. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You increment nn very often. Thus you will almost always find nn != 0. Thus your code will almost always conclude that there is not identity. IMHO your whole logic is completely unclear since it is already unclear what id1 and id2 are. It starts with the question what m[x][y] actually are.

You should also consider to avoid brute force searching altogether. That is: if G is a finite group, according to [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29), for every x in G you have x^|G| = e. Thus you can compute e directly. If you do not know in advance if G is a group then x^|G| is still the only possible candidate for e.

Comment: id1 is the first check of what's the identity (e * g = g). id2 is the second check of what's the identity (g * e = g). m[x][y] is an array containing the 4 numbers the program asks for when I run it.

Comment: m looks like a two dimensional array, so it is not clear how this fits the 16 possible index combinations if you have put only 4 numbers into it. Probably "m" is intended to be the operation but then you should not multiply as well.

Comment: In this case, multiplication, m is the multiplication table.

Comment: m[2][3] = 12 in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't you check if m[x][y] == m[y][x] and m[x][y] == x and then conclude that y is the identity?

Comment: I see now, I now computed l[x] * l[y] (m[x][y] is l[x] * l[y] in this program). Still having this problem.

Comment: I changed it to `if m[x][y] = m[y][x] then en = y` and it returned en as 3, when it should be 1.